# How to open a pop-up window in a different physical screen in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, popup, screen, window.open

Is there a way to open a pop-up (using `window.open`) and place it on a different physical screen?

This is possible in Firefox with:

```
window.open(location, '', 'width=200,height=200,left=-1052')
```

but Chrome prevents you from moving a child pop-up outside of the screen of the master page.

I assume they do this to prevent malicious websites from creating hidden pop-ups, but in the case where I do have two screens and want that pop-up to always open on my second one preventing it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

It is a know problem in Chrome, please star the issue so it gets looked at

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137681